# R: error handling in finding the row number of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, indexing, row

I have a dataframe with an ID column and another dummy column. In the first step the user enters a number which should be one of the IDs (ID_edit). Then the respective row index is determined. If the ID is in the dataframe everything works fine. If not (because the user enters a wrong ID or no ID at all) there should be an error message. I tried this:

```
  test_df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,3,6,8),
                        "char" = c("a","b","c","d"))

  ID_edit <- as.integer(2)
  row_nr_df <- which(test_df$ID == ID_edit, arr.ind=TRUE)

  View(test_df$ID)
  row_list <- as.numeric(rownames(test_df))

  if(!is.null(row_nr_df %in% row_list)) {
    print("Row number in row list")
  } else {
    print("Row number not in row list")}

  View(row_nr_df)
```

If I change

```
  ID_edit <- as.integer(1)
```

which is working, to

```
  ID_edit <- as.integer(2)
```

the if-statement is still TRUE, but I expect and want to have the else block here.

```
View(row_nr_df)
```

shows then the message "No data available in table".

In the end I want to access the dataframe with the row number, e.g.:

```
char_edit <- test_df$char[[row_nr_df]]
```

But this is not working, if the row number does not exist .

Comment: What is the expected result? Do you want to be able to access the dataframe by 1). row with the the ID that matches ID_edit if ID_edit is in ID if that exists and 2). directly by the row number given by ID_edit if it is not in the ID column? Or do you just want to know the row number and whether it's in the ID column?

Comment: The user enters an ID, which could be either an integer or simply nothing. Then check whether the entered ID is in 'test_df&ID' or not. a) If the ID is in 'test_df&ID' then find the respective row index 'row_nr_df' and access the dataframe 'test_df' with this index. b) If the ID is not in 'test_df&ID' or if the ID is empty (no integer) give an error warning (-> else statement).

Comment: So it doesn't need to say ("Row number in row list") if it is in the list, but instead just return the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 test_df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1,3,6,8),
                       "char" = c("a","b","c","d"))

 isin<-function(x,data)
 {if(length(which(data$ID == x, arr.ind=TRUE))>=1)
     {data[which(data$ID == x, arr.ind=TRUE),]}
   else{"not in list"}}

> isin(x=3,data=test_df)
  ID char
2  3    b
> isin(x=2,data=test_df)
[1] "not in list"
```